# Beautiful Soup: Extracting single elements from a tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to parse an HTML document. I have extracted the following tag.

```
<p>{
"url": "/name/abcdef”,
"name": “Max Mustermann”,
"jobTitle":"Director”,
"description": “Lorem Ipsum.”,
"birthDate": “2000-01-01”
}</p>
```

I wish to extract the birthdate, and nothing else. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: use the `json` module and parse the `.string` property of the tag as a json. Also you have wrong double quotes for instance around `Lorem Ipsum`, fix those.

Comment: @Niloct why not post that as an answer? I would have answered if not your comment

Comment: Because I would like the OP to try to come up with the code.